# Replacements within a mathematica expression?

Tags: replacement, output-formatting, formatting, expression-manipulation

Say I have many expressions of the form $$\text{expr} = \frac{1}{AB(C+D)^n E^m}$$ where $A,B,C,D$ and $E$ are symbols and $n,m$ arbitrary powers. In order to convert between the mathematica output and the output read by another software, I'd like to make the following replacements

`expr /. {1/A -> A^-1, 1/B -> B^-1, 1/(C+D)^n -> (C+D)^-n, 1/E^m -> E^-m}` so as to rewrite my expression equivalently as $$\text{expr} = A^{-1} B^{-1} (C+D)^{-n} E^{-m}$$

As far as I understand, mathematica would make replacements to my expression as a whole and not understand the subparts. Is there a way to enforce the replacement rule I described above?

Comment: It would be better to use `FullForm` to check the form to match first.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Thanks but then how to render e.g `Power[n2,-1]` as `n2^-1`? I need to do this otherwise my software won't know what it is.

Comment: I assume your "other" software is expecting a string as an input, e.g., "A^-1 * B^-1 * (C+D)^-n * E^-m", is that correct?

Comment: @Carl Woll yes, that’s correct, the terms have to be in multiplication as you wrote. I should have mentioned that. The other software by the way is Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in creating a string version of your input, where negative powers are not converted to fractions. As @Alexei implies in his answer, the fraction form only occurs for negative numbers, so you can prevent it by modifying the exponent so that it is not a negative number. His solution was to replace it with a symbol, but another idea is to add a wrapper to the exponent. Compare:

```
x^-1
x^Defer[-1]
```

> 1/x
>
> x^-1

Now, the usual function to create a string version is [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) with a second argument of [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) (never use a single-argument [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString)!). The problem with adding a wrapper is that [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) usually displays the wrapper. However, there is a special symbol, [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm), that is invisible in [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm), e.g.:

```
ToString[SequenceForm[-1], InputForm]
```

> "-1"

Putting the above pieces together, you can create a function to construct your desired string:

```
myForm[expr_] := ToString[
    expr /. Power[z_, n_] :> Power[z, SequenceForm[n]],
    InputForm
]
```

For your example:

```
myForm[1/(a b (c+d)^n e^m)]
```

> "a^-1*b^-1*(c + d)^-n*e^-m"

Finally, if you think you might have nested powers, the above function will need some modification so that all [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) objects acquire a [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) wrapper in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are various different OutputForms which aim to achieve something similair. InputForm seems to be similair to what you want to achieve.

You should allways include a minimal and complete example. I can't verify my code but this seems ok:

```
a = b/c
a // InputForm
```

Wolfram tutorial: [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FormsOfInputAndOutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let us be sure that you are aware that the capital symbols `C`, `D` and `E` are protected in Mma, and should not be used for algebra.

As for the terms like `(c+d)^-n`, Mma will anyway output it in the form you wish:

```
expr1 = 1/((c + d)^n*e^m)

(* (c + d)^-n e^-m  *)
```

However, the expressions like

```
expr2 = 1/(a*b)
(*  1/(a b)  *)
```

are returned in a different format for reasons internal for Mma. There are a few ways around. The concrete one depends upon your ultimate aim. Since you need to import it into a software that you tell nothing about, I propose a very simple way. Let us reserve a symbol, say, "s" for a unity, and replace all expressions like `1/a`by `a^-s`:

```
expr1*expr2 /. Power[A_, -1] -> A^-s

(* a^-s b^-s (c + d)^-n e^-m *)
```

Then you import it into your software, and only after that put `s=1`. Done.

Have fun!